# How to convert JSON to C# generic list of case-insensitive keyed dictionary?

Tags: c#, dictionary, json.net, json-deserialization, case-insensitive

I am bound to using Newtonsoft.Json (not complaining, just saying) to convert a serialized set of descriptors.  Ideally, I'd like to convert to a case-insensitive-keyed dictionary - but I'm not quite sure how to do that.

As a very contrived and simple example, the JSON:

```js
[
    { "property": "LastName", "value": "Buonarroti"},
    { "property": "FirstName", "value": "Michelangelo"}
]
```

Can be deserialized by:

```cs
var descriptors = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IList<Dictionary<string, string>>>(serializedJson);
```

However, `descriptors` will be comprised of case-*sensitive*-keyed dictionaries, whereas I'd like case-*insensitive*-keyed dictionaries.  I know (through trial), that I **cannot** do this:

```cs
var descriptors = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IList<Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)>>(serializedJson);
```

So how, when requesting `DeserializeObject` to convert into an `IList` of `Dictionary<string, string>`, do I request that each dictionary (within the list of dictionaries) all be created using `StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase`?  Is such at all possible?  I can't imagine (nor have I found) a method on the dictionary to convert it to a case-insensitive key *after* its instantiation (but one can hope).

I'm quite positive the best answer would be to create an extension method for the dictionary to render all keys case-insensitive before requesting a value by key - but just wondering if there was some already-in-place way to do what I'm requesting.

Comment: You can maybe have a look at the `Deserialization callbacks` https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationCallbacks.htm